# When one converts to Islam, do they have to make up prayers?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, shahada

When one converts to Islam, must they make up their prayer?

I have also wondered, in the situation of someone becoming a disbeliever, for example, for a day, would they have to catch up their prayers if they return to Islam sincerely?

Jazak Allahu Khayran, I am trying to improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Upon converting to Islam, all previous sins are forgiven, Alhamdullilah. Additionally, one does not have to makeup any prayers or fasts missed for the duration that one was non-Muslim. The Sacred Law rulings related to worship only apply to Muslims.

After one converted to Islam, if one subsequently missed any obligatory fasts or obligatory prayers, then one is obliged to make them up.